# Display Android screen on PC

Tags: android, streaming

We need to display our Android screen on a PC. We **don't** want to remotely control the device. We tried applications like `androidscreencast`, `droidAtScreen` etc. But their `fps` is very less. Is there any better application that can do this? Could you please suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way you can get higher `FPS`. Android has a limit of screenshots/second, it has something to do with the amount of time it takes to request the `framebuffer`, so live screen apps cannot exceed that frame rate.

Comment: Nonsense. `scrcpy` can get higher fps. Nobody said it had to use screenshots. ^^ … But in reality, of course the phone display *itself* has a fps limit. And the phone will not want to render more than that, unless you can tell it that your display is a separate one. The debug tools allow that, and then there’s HDMI-over-USB-C, but it can get complicated there.

Answer (score 1):

There is a built in functionality in Android, Use DDMS perspective in eclipse or DDMS application itself, there is an option "Capture Screen", it will give you screenshots not real live android screen. You will have to refresh to show current state of your android screen. See if there is any way to capture live too, I haven't found so.

Answer (score 0):

`scrcpy` does exactly what you need. It streams a screen capture via adb over usb or even wifi.

I had no problem getting 60 fps on my old PC, with a full HD smartphone. (You can show the FPS with Alt-I.)

Note that it is smart about this though, and won’t send frames unless it needs to. So it may show 6 fps when it idles. But when you open anything that moves, you’ll see it get 60 fps. Also note, that it may limit its max fps to 60, unless you change that with `--max-fps`.

With a modern PC with hardware video acceleration, it takes little resources, and kept my phone with a broken screen perfectly usable for a year. Including watching YouTube, messaging, or even using GPS navigation.

`scrcpy` also offers a lot of other functionality, like video capture, clipboard exchange, etc.